# About header-width,footer positon,the position of picture. My awful code doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my stupid and awful code.(HTML&CSS)
It's a copy of Airbnb's top page to study.

reference: https://www.airbnb.jp/host/homes?_set_bev_on_new_domain=1568702785_MTQxMDA4ZDc4ZmM0

1.header-width
    Somehow, My header-size of width is very short.
    I make it become longer the width of this site to 1050px.
    so the [header-right] has to become align right.

2.footer positon
    My footer stands around the center of the site somehow.

3.the position of picture
 In the div class[host-voice-wrapper],
 there is a picture(Emma) in the bottom.
But I want it to be the right of sentences.

```
1.check the original source code of Airbnb

1.
~HTML~
-----------
<header>
 <div class="header-left">
 <div class="header-logo">
 <img src="./img/246x0w.jpg">
 </div>
 <div class="header-list">
 <ul>
 <li>概要</li>
 <li>準備</li>
 <li>安全</li>
 <li>マネープラン</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>

-----------
~CSS~
-----------
header{
  height:60px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:10;
  background-color: white;

}

.header-left{
  float:left;
  display:flex;
}

.header-logo img{
  width:50px;
}

.header-list li{
  float:left;
  padding-right:30px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.header-list li:hover{
  border-bottom:1px solid #7f7f7f;
}

.header-right{
  float:right;
}

.expect-income{

}

.amount{
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.start{
  padding:10px 15px;
  background-color:#dc143c;
  color:white;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin:10px;
}

.start:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:0.3s;
}

-----------
2.
~HTML~
-----------
<footer>
        <img class="footer-logo" src="./img/246x0w.jpg">
        <a>
        Airbnb Global Services Limited
        観光庁長官(01)第S0001号(2018年6月15日-2023年6月14日)
        © 2019 Airbnb, Inc. All rights reserved.</a>
    </footer>
-----------
~CSS~
-----------
footer{
  height:40px;
  border-top:1px solid  #808080;
  padding:10px 0 30px 20px;
}

.footer-logo{
  width:20px;
}

footer a{
  font-size:15px;
}

-----------
3.
~HTML~
-----------
<div class="host-voice-wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="contents">
          <div class="voice">
            <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-2x my-orange"></i>
            <br></br>
            <a class="voice-text">「ホスト保証」があったからAirbnb参加を決めたといっても過言でないほどで、被害やトラブルがあったときに頼れるサポートがあるのは本当にありがたいですね。</a>
            <br>
            <a class="host-introduce">Emmaさんはロンドンのホスト。自由度の高さに魅力を感じています</a>
            <br>
            <a class="btn example">ホスト実践例をチェック</a>
          </div>
          <div class="Emma">
            <img src="./img/Emma.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
-----------

~CSS~
-----------
.host-voice-wrapper{
  margin-top:100px;

}

.contents{
  float:left;
}

.voice{
  width:40%;

}

.voice-text{
  font-size:30px;
}

.host-introduce{
  color:#808080;
}

.example{
  padding:15px 20px;
  border:2px solid #404040;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin-top:20px;
}

.Emma{

  width:400px;
}
-----------
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this code. hope it will work for you.

```css
body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 80px 0px;
}

.container {
 width: 1170px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px 15px;
}

header {
 height: 60px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 ;
 z-index: 10;
 background-color: white;
}

.header-left {
 float: left;
 display: flex;
}

.header-logo img {
 width: 50px;
}

.header-list li {
 float: left;
 padding-right: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.header-list li:hover {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
}

.header-right {
 float: right;
}

.amount {
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.start {
 padding: 10px 15px;
 background-color: #dc143c;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin: 10px;
}

.start:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: 0.3s;
}

footer {
 height: 40px;
}

.footer-logo {
 margin-right: 10px;
 width: 20px;
}

footer a {
 font-size: 15px;
}

.host-voice-wrapper {
 padding: 80px 0px;
}

.footer-content {
 border-top: 1px solid #808080;
 padding: 10px 0 20px;
}

.footer-content,
.contents {
 display: flex;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.voice {
 width: 40%;
}

.voice-text {
 font-size: 30px;
}

.host-introduce {
 color: #808080;
}

.example {
 padding: 15px 20px;
 border: 2px solid #404040;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.Emma {
 width: 50%;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="header-left">
        <div class="header-logo">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/logo-g-letter-on-white-260nw-497276758.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="header-list">
            <ul>
                <li>概要</li>
                <li>準備</li>
                <li>安全</li>
                <li>マネープラン</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="host-voice-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="contents">
            <div class="voice">
                <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-2x my-orange"></i>
                <br></br>
                <a class="voice-text">「ホスト保証」があったからAirbnb参加を決めたといっても過言でないほどで、被害やトラブルがあったときに頼れるサポートがあるのは本当にありがたいですね。</a>
                <br>
                <a class="host-introduce">Emmaさんはロンドンのホスト。自由度の高さに魅力を感じています</a>
                <br>
                <a class="btn example">ホスト実践例をチェック</a>
            </div>
            <div class="Emma">
                <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/logo-g-letter-on-white-260nw-497276758.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="footer-content">
            <img class="footer-logo" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/logo-g-letter-on-white-260nw-497276758.jpg">
            <a>
Airbnb Global Services Limited <br>
観光庁長官(01)第S0001号(2018年6月15日-2023年6月14日) <br>
© 2019 Airbnb, Inc. All rights reserved.
</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you for give me correct code.
I did run the site finally!
Thank you so much.

Somehow the question3 (the position of picture)
didn't work.
still remained to previous div"step-wrapper".

So I just add 10"<br>",
and aligned next line.

I really thank you again.
I ganna practice more and want to give you back in somewhat way.